# What are some strategies for unit testing workflows in WF 4?

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I've done quite a bit of WF development using 3.5 over the last few years, but am just now ramping up on WF in 4.0. I have a TDD bent, and while WF 3.5 was difficult at times to unit test, I'm wondering if anyone could share their strategy for unit testing workflows in WF 4 and/or point me to resources that would help get me started?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest approach is, just like in WF35, to separate the implementation from the activity so they can be tested independently of each other. The activity extension is just a regular class so use whatever you are comfortable with. Most activities can be unit tested quite easily using the WorklfowInvoker.

Comment: agreed, and I will certainly do that. That said, any testing examples or best practices from your own use that you'd like to share?

Comment: Big +1. There are some nice examples in the Pro WF 4 book by Bukovics.

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree with Maurice on testing activities independently. For unit testing workflow services, there is now [Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting](http://wf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Microsoft.Activities.UnitTesting%20Overview). Download from the [CodePlex page](http://wf.codeplex.com/).